# Deploying external files from visual studio with .NET CF application

Tags: compact-framework, .net-cf-3.5

I am working on a .NET CF 3.5 application. There are few external files\assemblies that the application is consuming. These files are not part of the project, therefore while debugging when I deploy the project, these external files are not deployed to the device.
Is there any way I can deploy these files with project without including them in the project?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get Studio to deploy arbitrary files without telling it what files to deploy.  The only way to tell Studio to deploy files is to either add the files to the project (as a Resource or a Content file) or by adding a reference to them (for .NET assemblies).